# global variable not contain value on viewdidload in swift

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables, nsjsonserialization

variable containing data(1) while printing under jsonserialization method but in viewdidload it's showing nil value(0)

```
    var bank = Int()

    func getProfile() {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String: Any]
    print("json \(json)")

let status = json["Success"] as! Bool

if status {
//send profile update status 1
//After Alert Success
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let banks = (json["bank"] as? NSString)?.intValue {


            print("banks\(banks)")
            self.bank = Int(banks)
            print("self.bank\(self.bank)")
        }
}



} else {


}
}
```

variable called under viewdidload showing 0(nil) value

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    getProfile()
    print("bank \(bank)")
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

output: bank 0

Comment: Where are you calling the function which contains json serialization ad the complete code

Comment: viewDIdLoad is called as soon the view is loaded after that your custom function executes provided that you place it in viwDidLoad or elsewhere

Comment: in viewdidload ,... getProfile()

Comment: I have updated code @MoazKhan

Comment: Don't call before super.viewDidLoad

Comment: are you sure you get a value in banks variable ?

Comment: I called after super.viewDidLoad but not working

Comment: yes, @MoazKhan value successfully coming in variable under json method

Comment: are you getting data from a webservice ?

Comment: yes, getting @MoazKhan ... problem in only calling variable in viewdidload , no other issue

Comment: The reason the property isn't set at `viewDidLoad` is because you are setting it asynchronously inside a `DispatchQueue`. You are fetching and setting your property in a different thread. You need to use callbacks or delegates if you want to be notified of when the property is set.

Comment: Your code does not show the context in which the `getProfile` method is being called. Given you use `DispatchQueue.main.async` to print something out suggests a threaded context. If this is done in parallel to displaying your `View` without synchronisation it is no wonder that `bank` is not set in `viewDidLoad`. You might consider opening your `View` only when your fetching thread has completed. However it is hard to show you how to do this if you do not share your calling context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue the variable isn't set because the webservice is called in another thread and the variable is printed before it's even loaded by the web service.

Try to call it again in some button and you will see your result will print perfectly

Comment: I need this on view load not on button click

Comment: I know but you didn't get my point. I am just saying it's not showing up because the work you are doing is in another thread view is already loaded and 0 is already printed after that your thread completes and gives you the result. After completion you can't expect the result in view unless you reload it.

Comment: Then you didn't do it right. All swift developers use threading and do this on daily basis. More context is required from you in order to make things more clear.